# Entity Framework 6 Mapping classes to a table based on a value in a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

A table has similar but unrelated data records

```
+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+
| RecordType |    Name    |  Surname  | DateOfBirth | DateOfIncorporation  |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+
| Person     | Luke       | SkyWalker | 1/1/1017    |                      |
| Company    | Jedi Order |           |             | 1/1/101              |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+
```

I would like to use two classes to handle this rather than having to always look at the RecordType (Person or Company).

This is an existing table and there is not an option to split the table in to two (ironically, this table was created using code first entity framework, but the table now cannot be modified)

Is there a way I can do this in entity framework ?

That is, when I use `Person class (context.Persons)` I only get records with RecordType "Person" and when I use `Company class (context.Companies)` I only get records with RecordType "Comapany" -

```
class Person 
{ 
string RecordType {get;set;} //This will only have "Person"
string Name {get;set;}
string Surname {get;set;}
DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
}

class Company
{ 
string RecordType {get;set;} //This will only have Company
string Name {get;set;}
DateTime DateOfIncorporation {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible with entity framework. The best guides to this I have found are [at this link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

**EDIT**

You're currently using Table-Per-Hierarchy, but if you follow that guide then you can do it in such a way as to be able to query efficiently over either Persons or Companies with strong types. For example,

```
var allRecords = myDbContext.RecordsTable;
var personRecords = allRecords.OfType<Person>();
var companyRecords = allRecords.OfType<Company>();
```

One nice perk of using this method is that calling `OfType()` does not force execution, so you can use it on an `IQueryable<T>` without fetching records too early. If your classes share all or almost all of the same properties, this is usually a good strategy. Otherwise, you'll want to use one of the other inheritance strategies.

Comment: This approach does require modifying the table as I understand OfType would create a discriminator (is there a way to configure a discriminator via Fluent API ?). But the big help is that I don't have to split the table.

Comment: I searched in the link above you provided and found some info about changing the discriminator ([link](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)) - will give this a try. Thank you again !!

Comment: Hey, yeah you should be able to tell Entity Framework which column is your discriminator, but I haven't had to map a table that I didn't actually create so I'm not sure if there's anything else you'll have to do. Good luck!